# Segmentation fault / list initializing

Tags: c

I want to create a list with the following structure:

- list.h: Contains function prototypes and defines data types
- lt.c: main function to test the list
- list.c: actual implementation of the list

When executing it I always get a segfault error. When trying to identify it with gdb it is shown that it is the fault of the following line in lt.c:

```
list_t *li=list_init();
```

The rest of my lt.c file looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

int main ( int argc, char *argv [ ], char *envp [ ] )
{
    list_t *li=list_init();
//li=list_init();
   /* if((li=list_init())==NULL)
    {
        perror (" Cannot allocate memory" ) ;
        exit(-1);
    }*/
}
```

My implementation of the list.c function list_init() is as follows:

```
list_t *list_init ()
{
    list_t* newlist = malloc(sizeof(*newlist));
if (!newlist)
{
    perror ("malloc-newlist");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}`enter code here`
   //newlist->first=NULL;
    //newlist->last=NULL;
newlist->first = (struct list_elem *) malloc(sizeof(struct list_elem));
newlist->last  = (struct list_elem *) malloc(sizeof(struct list_elem));
    return newlist;
}
```

My list.h file is as follows:

```
    struct list_elem {
    struct list_elem *next; // Zeiger auf das naechste Element
    char         *data; // Zeiger auf ein Datenobject
};

typedef struct list {
    struct list_elem *first;// erstes Element in der Liste
    struct list_elem *last; // letztes Element in der Liste
} list_t;

/* function prototypes */
list_t           *list_init ();
```

However, I do not know how I could change the implementation so that it does not occur anymore.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

While it is impossible to tell where your problem lies exactly, I suspect it lies in one of two places. One, you are initializing each `data` member with a *string literal* which is read-only on all but a very few systems. So if anywhere in your code you attempt to modify `data` you could expect a SegFault. The same would apply if you later attempt to `free (pointer->data);`

Two, you fail of assign your `node->next` pointers correctly leading to your traversal attempting to derefernce a `NULL` pointer or *indeterminate* pointer leading to the same SegFault. This can occur if your `append` function fails to handle the `if (!list->first) { ... }` case correctly or the `else` case where you will be required to set `pointer->next = newnode;`

There is really no way to tell unless you post a [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but given list operations are somewhat generic, you could correct the shortcomings with something similar to the following for your `init()` and `append()` functions (with an added `print()` and `free()` functions thrown in for good measure), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_elem {
    struct list_elem *next;     // Zeiger auf das naechste Element
    char *data;                 // Zeiger auf ein Datenobject
};

typedef struct list {
    struct list_elem *first;// erstes Element in der Liste
    struct list_elem *last; // letztes Element in der Liste
} list_t;

/* function prototypes */
list_t *list_init ();
struct list_elem *list_append (list_t *list, char *data);
void list_print (list_t *list);
void list_free (list_t *list);

int main (void)
{
    list_t *li = list_init();

    if (list_append (li, (char[]){"erstes"}) == NULL || 
        list_append (li, (char[]){"zweites"}) == NULL ||
        list_append (li, (char[]){"drittes"}) == NULL) {
        perror ("Cannot allocate memory" ) ;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    list_print (li);
    list_free (li);

    exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

list_t *list_init (void)
{
    list_t *newlist = malloc (sizeof *newlist);

    if (!newlist) {
        perror ("malloc-newlist");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newlist->first = NULL;
    newlist->last = NULL;

    return newlist;
}

struct list_elem *list_append (list_t *list, char *data)
{
    struct list_elem *node = NULL;

    if (!list)
        return NULL;

    if (!(node = malloc (sizeof *node))) {
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }
    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (!list->first)
        list->first = node;
    else {
        struct list_elem *iter = list->first;
        while (iter->next)
            iter = iter->next;
        iter->next = node;
    }

    return (list->last = node);
}

void list_print (list_t *list)
{
    struct list_elem *iter = NULL;

    if (!list)
        return;

    iter = list->first;

    while (iter) {
        printf ("%s\n", iter->data);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}

void list_free (list_t *list)
{
    struct list_elem *iter = NULL;

    if (!list)
        return;

    iter = list->first;

    while (iter) {
        struct list_elem *victim = iter;
        iter = iter->next;
        free (victim);
    }

    free (list);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_list_elem
erstes
zweites
drittes
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ll_list_elem
==22383== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22383== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22383== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22383== Command: ./bin/ll_list_elem
==22383==
erstes
zweites
drittes
==22383==
==22383== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22383==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22383==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 64 bytes allocated
==22383==
==22383== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22383==
==22383== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22383== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

**Using `last` pointer with Forward-Chaining**

Since you have a `last` pointer there is no need for a generic iteration of the list to find the last pointer. I suspect you are intending to use forward-chaining. In that case, you can simply modify `append()` as follows:

```
    if (!list->first)
        list->first = node;
    else
        list->last->next = node;
```

(**note:** the `list->last = node` assignment is handled in the `return`)

Comment: I suspect you are correct -- added an example of forward-chaining with `last`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

You have written: "You are initializing each data member with a string literal which is read-only on all but a very few systems.". -> How can I change that?

Comment: Look how I used a *"Compound Literal"* to cast the *string literals* to `(char []){...}` making them an *array of char* (which you can change -- but not make longer). Note: the *compound literal* is only available C99+ or by specific compiler extension.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not allocate memory in proper way.

```
TList *list_init()
{
   TList *newList = (TList *) malloc(sizeof(TList));

   newList->first = (struct list_elem *) malloc(sizeof(structlist_elem));
   newList->last  = (struct list_elem *) malloc(sizeof(struct list_elem));

newList->first->next= NULL;
newList->last->next= NULL;

return newList;
}
```

Comment: This code is weird, there are typos, the types are not the same as in the question and it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Allocating for `first` and `last` in `init()` will greatly complicate your `append()` function. (not to mention updating `last`)

Comment: @Jabberwocky , because we don't have enough information of list append.